# Mail not delivered to custom email addresses (e.g. me@mycompanyname.com) with Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, phpmailer

I am running Joomla 1.5.15. After working on my site, I decided to test it with different email addresses to make sure that everyone would be able to register. There was no problem with hotmail, yahoo, gmail, etc but I noticed that when I registered with my company email address, I did not receive any mail asking me to activate my account. The message on Joomla said that my account has been created and the activation has been sent but when I check my mail, I don’t see anything. I then decided to test with some other customized emails and I noticed that Joomla could not send mails to most of them.

I was just wondering whether it is a problem of Joomla’s mailing system or whether it is the server settings on the place where the email addresses are that is causing the problem. I spoke with the live support of my company’s website host and they told me I have to change certain things on my server before the mails could be delivered. I then went ahead and made those changes and the mails were delivered.

My problem was solved but then what of the other people (with customized emails) that would want to register on the site and do not know all these, does it mean that Joomla is not a good option for them or is there anything I could do to make Joomla send mails to everybody just like any of these mailing systems would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some people are receiving them and other's not, then I would suggest that it's a server issue. If you're sending out

name@domain.com

but the website is on

notdomain.com

then many servers will flag it as spam as the domain and the sender don't match, unless you use SMTP

Comment: Ok so please how do I use SMTP?

Comment: I would like to use GMail as my SMTP server

Comment: In the Joomla config options, select SMTP. You then need to enter your server address (probably smtp.Gmail.com), your username and password. You may need to enable SSL as well, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Who is your email hosted with? If it's hosted on the server where you host the website then you should have a control panel to log into (e.g. cPanel, Plesk). You can add new email addresses under the options in there.
If you don't have email set up then I reccommend using Google Apps for your domain. You can have gMail, Google Docs, Google Calendar and all of the Google applications on your domain. For email you can have hello@mydomain.com.
I use Google Apps on all of my domains. It is easy to use and also if you have to move hosts, there is not need to change your email settings as they stay the same.

Heres the link for the Standard (free) edition of Google Apps
http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html

Comment: My problem is sending mails from Joomla (using the JUtility class) to to people that are using customized email accounts. Many of these emails are not delivered so I want to know whether it is Joomla's problem or the host's problem